# C macro with #ifdef

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4

I'm wondering if there is a better way of implementing this code :

```
if (strcmp(port_p, all_ports_a[inc++]) == 0)
    {
        #ifdef GPIOA
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, all_pins_a[offset] , atoi(args[OFF_VALUE_WRITE]));
            SER_send("Value written\r", strlen("Value written\r"));
            return 1;
        #endif
        //b
    }else if (strcmp(port_p, all_ports_a[inc++]) == 0){
        #ifdef GPIOB
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, all_pins_a[offset] , atoi(args[OFF_VALUE_WRITE]));
            SER_send("Value written\r", strlen("Value written\r"));
            return 1;
        #endif
        //c
    }else if (strcmp(port_p, all_ports_a[inc++]) == 0){
        #ifdef GPIOC
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, all_pins_a[offset] , atoi(args[OFF_VALUE_WRITE]));
            SER_send("Value written\r", strlen("Value written\r"));
            return 1;
        #endif
        //etc.
```

especially this part :

```
#ifdef GPIOA
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, all_pins_a[offset] , atoi(args[OFF_VALUE_WRITE]));
      SER_send("Value written\r", strlen("Value written\r"));
      return 1;
#endif
```

i want to replace that by a macro, something like :

MY_MACRO(GPIOx, MESSAGE) :

```
#ifdef GPIOx
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOx, all_pins_a[offset] , atoi(args[OFF_VALUE_WRITE]));
      SER_send(MESSAGE, MESSAGE);
      return 1;
#endif
```

I know that we can't add #ifdef in a macro but maybe I missed something ? One line instead of 5 would be really nice !

Thanks !

AJT

Comment: don't you know how to define a macro with `#define` ?

Comment: I'd question the fundamental program design before anything else. Why are you mixing string comparisons with GPIO? That's a fishy combination... are these strings coming in through an UART terminal or something? If so, you should 1) parse the input, 2) find out which port it is specifying 3) translate that to an integer index 0 to n 4) activate the port corresponding to that index. You should find yourself with an array of `volatile uint32_t*` that either points at GPIO ports or NULL, depending on if the port exists or not. Generate that table through pre-processor `#idef` or similar.

Comment: If the then-clauses are going to be empty when various symbols are not defined, you  can also omit the `strcmp` tests (with minor changes so `inc` is managed properly).

Comment: @Lundin ,   yes i send commands via a serial link (UART in in my case) to configure ports, read pins etc.
**config command example** : gpio_config a 5 opp nopull flow none\r
**write command example** : gpio_write a 5 1\r

parsing the command is done in another part of my program, my application is a shell implemented on a MCU (STM32Fxx for the moment, so my code should compile on all STM32Fxx )that retrieves commands and process it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible solution, although it is probably not an improvement on the original code!

```
#ifdef GPIOA
#define MY_MACRO_GPIOA(MESSAGE) MY_MACRO_(GPIOA, MESSAGE)
#else
#define MY_MACRO_GPIOA(MESSAGE) do; while (0)
#endif

#ifdef GPIOB
#define MY_MACRO_GPIOB(MESSAGE) MY_MACRO_(GPIOB, MESSAGE)
#else
#define MY_MACRO_GPIOB(MESSAGE) do; while (0)
#endif

#ifdef GPIOC
#define MY_MACRO_GPIOC(MESSAGE) MY_MACRO_(GPIOC, MESSAGE)
#else
#define MY_MACRO_GPIOC(MESSAGE) do; while (0)
#endif

#define MY_MACRO_(GPIOx, MESSAGE) \
    do { \
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOx, all_pins_a[offset] , atoi(args[OFF_VALUE_WRITE])); \
        SER_send(MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE)); \
        return 1; \
    } while (0)

#define MY_MACRO(GPIOx, MESSAGE) MY_MACRO_##GPIOx(MESSAGE)
```

...

```
    if (strcmp(port_p, all_ports_a[inc++]) == 0)
        MY_MACRO(GPIOA, "Value written\r");
    else if (strcmp(port_p, all_ports_a[inc++]) == 0)
        MY_MACRO(GPIOB, "Value written\r");
    else if (strcmp(port_p, all_ports_a[inc++]) == 0)
        MY_MACRO(GPIOC, "Value written\r");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something completely different. Arrange data in tables, then find row with matching name, and use values on the row.

First define table with all necessary data:

```
// Definition of single row
typedef struct {
    char name[NAME_MAX];
    GPIO_T gpio;
    char message[MESSAGE_MAX];
} Port_T;

// Table with all rows
Port_T const ports[] = {
#ifdef GPIOA
    { "GPIOA", GPIOA, "GPIOA message" },
#endif
#ifdef GPIOB
    { "GPIOB", GPIOB, "GPIOB message" },
#endif
 ...
};
// Number of rows on the table
size_t const portCount = sizeof ports / sizeof *ports;
```

Then replace `if/else` chain with `for` loop:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<portCount; ++i) {
    Port_T const * port = &ports[i];
    if(strcmp(port_p, port->name) == 0) {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(port->gpio, all_pins_a[offset], atoi(args[OFF_VALUE_WRITE]));
        SER_send(port->message, strlen(port->message));
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You could also use more advanced search routines than simple `for` loop, like binary search.

Comment: ok that's nice ! I will try that later ! Thanks for your answer 
This is more generic and i could use this for loop in different functions instead of my tons of **if**